# Dealing with many SQL Parameters

Tags: sql, vb.net

I've actually 2 kinds of register in my form

1. Cliente
2. Sacado

Both uses almost the same fields, "Cliente" register have more field options.

I did this string maker for SQL command, it works ok, but it's not fast.

```vb
Private Sub SQLString()
    Dim LabelsItens = ArrayLabelsItens()
        Dim String_Labels = "", String_Itens As String = ""

        Dim n As Integer

        For n = 0 To LabelsItens.GetLength(0) - 1
            If n = LabelsItens.GetLength(0) - 1 Then
                String_Itens &= LabelsItens(n, 0)
                String_Labels &= $"'{LabelsItens(n, 2)}'"
            Else
                String_Itens &= LabelsItens(n, 0) & ","
                String_Labels &= $"'{LabelsItens(n, 2)}',"
            End If
        Next
End Sub

Public Function ArrayLabelsItens() As Array

    If Cliente = True Then
        Return {{"Nome", TB_Nome, TB_Nome.Text, TypeName(TB_Nome)},
        {"Documento", TB_Doc, TB_Doc.Text, TypeName(TB_Doc)},
        {"Endereco", TB_Endereco, TB_Endereco.Text, TypeName(TB_Endereco)},
        {"Numero", TB_Numero, TB_Numero.Text, TypeName(TB_Numero)},
        {"Bairro", TB_Bairro, TB_Bairro.Text, TypeName(TB_Bairro)},
        {"CEP", TB_CEP, TB_CEP.Text, TypeName(TB_CEP)},
        {"Cidade", TB_Cidade, TB_Cidade.Text, TypeName(TB_Cidade)},
        {"Estado", TB_Estado, TB_Estado.Text, TypeName(TB_Estado)},
        {"Observacoes", TB_Observacoes, TB_Observacoes.Text, TypeName(TB_Observacoes)},
        {"Tel1", TB_Telefone_1, TB_Telefone_1.Text, TypeName(TB_Telefone_1)},
        {"Tel2", TB_Telefone_2, TB_Telefone_2.Text, TypeName(TB_Telefone_2)},
        {"Tel3", TB_Telefone_3, TB_Telefone_3.Text, TypeName(TB_Telefone_3)},
        {"Tel4", TB_Telefone_4, TB_Telefone_4.Text, TypeName(TB_Telefone_4)},
        {"Email1", TB_Email_1, TB_Email_1.Text, TypeName(TB_Email_1)},
        {"Email2", TB_Email_2, TB_Email_2.Text, TypeName(TB_Email_2)},
        {"Email3", TB_Email_3, TB_Email_3.Text, TypeName(TB_Email_3)},
        {"Fator", TB_Fator, TB_Fator.Text, TypeName(TB_Fator)},
        {"Advalore", TB_Advalore, TB_Advalore.Text, TypeName(TB_Advalore)},
        {"LimiteValor", TB_L_Valor, TB_L_Valor.Text, TypeName(TB_L_Valor)},
        {"LimiteCredito", TB_L_Credito, TB_L_Credito.Text, TypeName(TB_L_Credito)},
        {"DataCadastro", TB_Data_Cadastro, TB_Data_Cadastro.Value, TypeName(TB_Data_Cadastro)},
        {"Credito", CB_Credito, CB_Credito.Checked, TypeName(CB_Credito)},
        {"Pendencias1", CB_Pendencias_1, CB_Pendencias_1.Checked, TypeName(CB_Pendencias_1)},
        {"Pendencias2", CB_Pendencias_2, CB_Pendencias_2.Checked, TypeName(CB_Pendencias_2)},
        {"Pendencias3", CB_Pendencias_3, CB_Pendencias_3.Checked, TypeName(CB_Pendencias_3)}}
    Else
        Return {{"Nome", TB_Nome, TB_Nome.Text, TypeName(TB_Nome)},
        {"Documento", TB_Doc, TB_Doc.Text, TypeName(TB_Doc)},
        {"Endereco", TB_Endereco, TB_Endereco.Text, TypeName(TB_Endereco)},
        {"Numero", TB_Numero, TB_Numero.Text, TypeName(TB_Numero)},
        {"Bairro", TB_Bairro, TB_Bairro.Text, TypeName(TB_Bairro)},
        {"CEP", TB_CEP, TB_CEP.Text, TypeName(TB_CEP)},
        {"Cidade", TB_Cidade, TB_Cidade.Text, TypeName(TB_Cidade)},
        {"Estado", TB_Estado, TB_Estado.Text, TypeName(TB_Estado)},
        {"Observacoes", TB_Observacoes, TB_Observacoes.Text, TypeName(TB_Observacoes)},
        {"Tel1", TB_Telefone_1, TB_Telefone_1.Text, TypeName(TB_Telefone_1)},
        {"Tel2", TB_Telefone_2, TB_Telefone_2.Text, TypeName(TB_Telefone_2)},
        {"Tel3", TB_Telefone_3, TB_Telefone_3.Text, TypeName(TB_Telefone_3)},
        {"Tel4", TB_Telefone_4, TB_Telefone_4.Text, TypeName(TB_Telefone_4)},
        {"Email1", TB_Email_1, TB_Email_1.Text, TypeName(TB_Email_1)},
        {"Email2", TB_Email_2, TB_Email_2.Text, TypeName(TB_Email_2)},
        {"Email3", TB_Email_3, TB_Email_3.Text, TypeName(TB_Email_3)},
        {"DataCadastro", TB_Data_Cadastro, TB_Data_Cadastro.Value, TypeName(TB_Data_Cadastro)},
        {"Credito", CB_Credito, CB_Credito.Checked, TypeName(CB_Credito)},
        {"Pendencias1", CB_Pendencias_1, CB_Pendencias_1.Checked, TypeName(CB_Pendencias_1)},
        {"Pendencias2", CB_Pendencias_2, CB_Pendencias_2.Checked, TypeName(CB_Pendencias_2)},
        {"Pendencias3", CB_Pendencias_3, CB_Pendencias_3.Checked, TypeName(CB_Pendencias_3)}}
    End If

End Function

' Then execute SQL commands and etc etc etc...
```

It'll output something like that, it works, but it's slow.

```sql
UPDATE TAB_SACADOS 
SET NOME = 'NAME OF GUY', 
    DOCUMENTO = '0115648787',
    ENDERECO = 'AVENUE A', 
    NUMERO = '15', 
    BAIRRO = '90 ROCK', 
    CEP = '80.000-000', 
    CIDADE = 'BALBOA', 
    ESTADO = 'RS', 
    OBSERVACOES = '', 
    TEL1 > = '(55)55555-5556', TEL2 = '', TEL3 = '', TEL4 = '', 
    EMAIL1 = '', EMAIL2 = '', EMAIL3 = '', 
    DATACADASTRO = '27/09/2019 00:00:00',
    CREDITO = 'FALSE', PENDENCIAS1 = 'FALSE', PENDENCIAS2 = 'FALSE',
    PENDENCIAS3 = 'FALSE' WHERE ID = 3
```

After some research in internet, I found the function `.Parameters.Addwithvalue`, seems to be the correct way to use it. But I'm trying to figure out how to make a function which will return all these parameters (or anything that's better/practical).

I could do like this for every INSERT, DELETE and UPDATE function, but that's not practical.

```vb
.Parameters.Addwithvalue(@ID, objid.value)
.Parameters.Addwithvalue(@Name, name.text)
.Parameters.Addwithvalue(@Address, fieldaddress.text)
```

I need help in that point, improving this **working** code. Any suggestion?

Comment: Yes, it is practical.  That is what you should be doing, except that you should be using `Add` rather than `AddWithValue` because the data types inferred by `AddWithValue` are not always correct.  The fact that you think that it's a lot of code write doesn't make it the wrong thing to do.

Comment: What are TX_Nome, TX_Doc etc? Are these the names of TextBoxes? Are there separate tables for Cliente and Sacado?

Comment: They're textboxes, they're the same fields in both tables...

Comment: @jmcilhinney Yes... But is there any other way to simple it? I mean, not repeat the Add's in every update, insert or delete of SQL...

Comment: @HeitorBadotti you only need to repeat them once each for INSERT and UPDATE. Delete just needs the primary key to delete. You should have a separate query/Stored Procedure for each of the two tables for each action (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, SELECT). Alternatively, if these two tables are so familiar, you can always make **one** table, with a field called RecordType which will hold a value indicating Cliente or Sacado. For the record type that doesn't need the few fields, leave them with NULL values.

Comment: You need to add all the required parameters for each command to that command.  You shouldn't be performing the same action, e.g. an insert to one particular table, in more than one place.  That's why data access code should be separate to business logic and presentation code.  If you have the data access code written such that each required command exists once, you can then invoke that code in multiple places if necessary.  That means that you can execute that command in multiple places but add the parameters once.